# Select Option não busca ou não grava o valor selecionado pelo usuário

Tags: php

Estou tentando pegar o valor selecionado pelo usuário em uma `option` faz dias e não tem jeito não estou conseguindo uso duas tabelas uma chamada contato e outra situação, na situação tenho os valores esperando, andamento e concluído.

Faço uma busca nesta tabela com `fecth_array` até ai tudo bem porém quando eu seleciono umas das opções não estou sabendo gravar e enviar a variável para a tabela contato. Peço ajuda de vocês pois já estou neste dilema a dias um

Obs.: Quando clico no botão alterar não esta enviando a variável que o usuário selecionou e sim o ultimo item do array que é concluído então mesmo que eu escolha andamento esta levando a variável concluído.

```
echo'<td><select name="sitprot" id="sitprot">';
$sql="select * from situacao"; // neste permite  mostrar e alterar e as opções para ser gravado no banco.
$resultado2=mysql_query($sql);
while($dados1=mysql_fetch_array($resultado2)){
    $marca1=$dados1['situ'];
    echo "<option value='$marca1'>$marca1</option>";
    echo $marca1;
}
echo '</select> <td>';   
echo '<td><a href="status1.php?id='.$info[id].'& situ='.$marca1.'">Alterar</td>';
```

Comment: Se está iniciando no PHP comece não usando as funções mysql_*, [Por que não devemos usar funções do tipo mysql_*?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/579/91). vc faze envio pelo link? ou tem mais algum código ai?

Comment: obrigado pela dica das funções mudarei para PDO ou msqli como sugestionado , sim uso o link mesmo passando as variaveis id e situ como mostra na ultima linha .

Comment: Tem um outro while dentro desse?

Comment: Leonardo,  ou vc usa um form e um botão para fazer um submit, ou faz como o KaduAmaral fez na resposta dele.  Com form e um botão de submit seria um pouco mais simples.

Answer (score 2):

Isso acontece porque o `while` ficou alterando a variável `$marca1` durante todo o *loop*, quando terminou a variável ficou com o último valor do *loop*, exemplo:

```
$i = 0;
while($i++ < 10){
   $marca = $i;
}

echo $marca; // Resultado: 9 - último valor dentro do while
```

Então, você tem que pegar o valor do `option` com Javascript:

```html
<select name="sitprot" id="sitprot">
  <option value="1">Valor 1</option>
  <option value="2">Valor 2</option>
  <option value="3">Valor 3</option>
  <option value="4">Valor 4</option>
</select>
<a href="#" id="alterar">Alterar</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('alterar').addEventListener('click', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var valor = document.getElementById('sitprot').value;
  var link = 'status1.php?id=<?=$info["id"]?>&situ='+valor;
  alert(valor);
  alert(link);
  //document.location.href = link;
});
</script>
```

Obs.: Notei que sua variável `$info[id]` está sem aspas, **sempre** use aspas (simples) em *array* associativos, exemplo: `$info['id']`.

Answer (score 1):

Obrigado Primeiramente pelo apoio bom

Abaixo coloquei o seu codigo dentro do php então usei echo

echo '';
  echo 'Valor 1';
  echo 'Valor 2';
  echo ' Valor 3';
  echo  'Valor 4';
  echo ' '; 
  echo 'Alterar';

**depois coloquei dentro das tags head html o script**

document.getElementById('alterar').addEventListener('click', function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
  var valor = document.getElementById('sitprot').value;
  var link = 'status1.php?id=&situ='+valor;
  alert(valor);
  alert(link);
  //document.location.href = link;
});

não deu erro , porém quando clico em alterar e parece não entrar no script e não mostrar o alert

[image: tela]

```html
<select name="sitprot" id="sitprot">
  <option value="1">Valor 1</option>
  <option value="2">Valor 2</option>
  <option value="3">Valor 3</option>
  <option value="4">Valor 4</option>
</select>
<a href="#" id="alterar">Alterar</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('alterar').addEventListener('click', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var valor = document.getElementById('sitprot').value;
  var link = 'status1.php?id=<?=$info["id"]?>&situ='+valor;
  alert(valor);
  alert(link);
  //document.location.href = link;
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Existem dois tipos de ciclo de vida de uma aplicação web:

1. Lado do servidor
2. Lado do cliente

Como você quer que o link para a alteração receba um valor que muda de acordo com a sua manipulação da aplicação no Lado Cliente (no browser), você deve usar Javascript para alterar o href do link e não PHP, ao menos na parte que tem a ver com o fator Situação.

O código já está disponível nas outras respostas, então vou deixar uma resposta usando jQuery, abaixo:

```js
$(function () {

  $('#link').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var situ = $('#sitprot option:selected').val();
    var id = /*<?php echo (int)$info['id']; ?>;*/ 1;
    var newUrl = 'status1.php?id=' + id + '&situ=' + situ;
    if (situ != 0)
      /*location.href = newUrl;*/alert('redireciona para ' + newUrl);
    else
      alert('selecione situação, por favor');
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id='f' name='f'>
  <select id='sitprot' name='sitprot'>
    <option value='0'>[selecione um valor]</option>
    <option>esperando</option>
    <option>andamento</option>
    <option>concluído</option>
  </select>
</form>
<br />
<a href="#" id="link">Alterar</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

Verifique se funciona, substituindo `echo "<option value='$marca1'>$marca1</option>";` por
`echo "<option value='{$marca1}'>{$marca1}</option>";`

Comment: tentei porém deu na mesma coisa se estivesse usando o meu option obrigado